# variable can not be resolved

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm working through the book Beginning BlackBerry 7 Development and really putting my little or non existent oop/java skills to the test- eclipse is throwing up an error from the code in the book stating that loginhandler hasn't been declared- and yes its correct- it hasn't been declared but it also hasn't been declared in the book.

What has been done is an inner class called logincommandhandler (at the bottom of my code) which can be seen in an excerpt  here- http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781430230151/chapter-4-user-interface-basics/67 - this is what its meant to be calling (i assume) but my limited oop skills i do not know what loginHandler should be- should it be defined somewhere with a type?

(there is no erata for the book)

```
package com.beginningblackberry.uifun;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.PasswordEditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.SeparatorField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.CheckboxField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.util.StringProvider;

import net.rim.device.api.command.Command;
import net.rim.device.api.command.CommandHandler;
import net.rim.device.api.command.ReadOnlyCommandMetadata;

public class UiFunMainScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

    BitmapField img;
    EditField usernameField;
    PasswordEditField passwordField;
    ObjectChoiceField domainField;
    CheckboxField rememberCheckBox;
    ButtonField clearButton, loginButton;

    public UiFunMainScreen(){
        Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/upd8rLOGO.png");


        img = new BitmapField(logoBitmap, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);     
        add(img);
        add(new SeparatorField());
        add(new LabelField("Please Enter Your Credentials:"));



        usernameField = new EditField("Username:","");
        passwordField = new PasswordEditField("Password:","");
        domainField = new ObjectChoiceField("Domain",new String[] {"Home","Work"});
        rememberCheckBox = new CheckboxField("Remember password",false);
        add(usernameField);add(passwordField);
        add(domainField);
        add(rememberCheckBox);

        add(new SeparatorField());
        clearButton = new ButtonField("Clear",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        loginButton = new ButtonField("Login",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);

        HorizontalFieldManager buttonManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
        buttonManager.add(clearButton);
        buttonManager.add(loginButton);

        add(buttonManager);

        clearButton.setChangeListener(this);
        //loginButton.setChangeListener(this);
        loginButton.setCommand(new Command(LoginHandler));


    }
    //routing
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){

        if(field == clearButton){
            clearTextFields();
        }else if(field == loginButton){
            login();
        }
    }


    private void login(){
        if(usernameField.getTextLength()== 0 || passwordField.getTextLength() == 0){
            Dialog.alert("You must enter a username and password");
        }
        else
        {
            String username = usernameField.getText();
            String selectedDomain = (String) domainField.getChoice(domainField.getSelectedIndex());
            LoginSuccessScreen loginSuccessScreen = new LoginSuccessScreen(username, selectedDomain);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(loginSuccessScreen);
        }

    }
    public void clearTextFields ()
    {
        usernameField.setText("");
        passwordField.setText("");

    }
    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance){
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        /*
        menu.add(new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Login"),20,10){

            public void run(){
                login();
            }   
        });
        */

        //login menu item       
        MenuItem loginMenu = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Login"),20,10);
        loginMenu.setCommand(new Command(LoginHandler));
        menu.add(loginMenu);


        //clear text menu item
        menu.add(new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Clear"),20,10){
            public void run(){
                clearTextFields();
            }   
        });
    }

    class LoginCommandHandler extends CommandHandler
    {

        public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context){
            login();
        }
    }


}
```

and the error-

```
LoginHandler cannot be resolved to a variable   UiFunMainScreen.java    /UiFun/src/com/beginningblackberry/uifun    line 69 Java Problem
```

any blackberry/java wizards shed some light on where i am going wrong?

**Update**

No one really answered the question bang on- to call the new inner class i called this instead

```
MenuItem loginMenu = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Login"),20,10);
loginMenu.setCommand(new Command(new LoginCommandHandler()));
menu.add(loginMenu);
```

**update 2 second answer**

Declaring loginHandler as a class variable also works -

```
LoginCommandHandler loginHandler = new LoginCommandHandler();
```

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/command/Command.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that it should be an instance of `LoginCommandHandler` (the class declared at the end). It's a guess, but an educated one: `Command`'s constructor expects a `CommandHandler` instance, and `LoginCommandHandler` extends `CommandHandler`, so...

The easy change is to change all the places that look like this:

```
loginButton.setCommand(new Command(LoginHandler));
```

to:

```
loginButton.setCommand(new Command(new LoginCommandHandler()));
```

E.g., we're calling the `LoginCommandHandler` constructor and passing the resulting object into `new Command()`.

Or if for some reason (I haven't really read the code) you need a reference to the handler, declare and instantiate it:

```
LoginCommandHandler loginHandler = new LoginCommandHandler();
```

...and then use it

```
loginButton.setCommand(new Command(loginHandler));
```

(Note that there are multiple places where they've made this mistake in the that quoted code.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing this line

```
 LoginCommandHandler loginHandler = new LoginCommandHandler();
```

Moreover you can get code for the book [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430230151).

Comment: +1 for the source code link. The "missing line" isn't the full answer, because they've also used `LoginHandler` rather than `loginHandler`, but hey...

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, the error is in line 69, which I assume is this:

```
 loginButton.setCommand(new Command(LoginHandler));
```

Assuming `LoginHandler` is the name of a class or interface, this line is invalid.
It should be something like `new Command(LoginHandler.class)`, `new Command(new LoginHandler())` or maybe `new Command("LoginHandler")`, since the parameter requires you to pass an object (the type object for a class would be `<classname>.class`).

If it should be a variable, then it simply doesn't exist (btw. Java convention is that variable names start with a lower case letter) and you have to create it.

> ... it hasn't been declared but it also hasn't been declared in the book.  ... (there is no erata for the book)

This doesn't mean the code in the book is 100% correct and compilable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
loginButton.setCommand(new Command(LoginHandler));
```

You proabably need a instance of LoginHandler (new LoginHandler()) to pass to new Command method.